# Xcode error -19011

Tags: xcode

I'm new to Xcode, and I have just finished creating my first iPhone application. I'm now trying to archive it to publish it. But, I keep getting this error :

```
Validate /Users/mannyrothman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LASD_Mobile-avjipewnjellnpgfnksgomejhqim/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LASDMobile/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/LASDMobile.app
    cd "/Users/mannyrothman/Documents/LASD Mobile copy"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/mannyrothman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LASD_Mobile-avjipewnjellnpgfnksgomejhqim/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LASDMobile/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/LASDMobile.app

Unable to validate your application. - (null)Executable=/Users/mannyrothman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LASD_Mobile-avjipewnjellnpgfnksgomejhqim/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LASDMobile/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/LASDMobile.app/LASDMobilecodesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation/Users/mannyrothman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LASD_Mobile-avjipewnjellnpgfnksgomejhqim/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LASDMobile/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/LASDMobile.app: valid on disk/Users/mannyrothman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LASD_Mobile-avjipewnjellnpgfnksgomejhqim/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LASDMobile/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/LASDMobile.app: satisfies its Designated Requirementtest-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1) - (null)
```

Comment: Did you install the certificates correctly provided by your Apple Developer Account? Seems that the entries couldn't be found. Check the organizer in Xcode if each certificate got a green tick behind it.

Comment: Please check this helpful tutorial about this topic explaining the process of getting your app on your phone for testing and the app to the App Store. http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

Comment: [link] (http://oi46.tinypic.com/34dfqsm.jpg)

Comment: The Distribution Profile seems to be missing.

Comment: WOW! Thank you soooo much! My app is now being reviewed!!!

Comment: Updated my answers to an answer so that the community can review your question. Glad I could help! Feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screen provided by @fcpwiz]

Your screenshot shows that there is no Distribution Profile available in Xcode's organizer. Create the profile in the Apple Developer Portal, download them via "Refresh" and be sure to use this profile for your needed operations.